# Clarification regarding a group theory proof

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

*In a group we have $abc = cba$. If $c \neq 1$, is the group abelian?* See [the following link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299038/in-a-group-we-have-abc-cba-is-it-abelian?newsletter=1&nlcode=117757%7c9b21).

(I am new to this site but it is my understanding that you cannot PM authors, correct? Which is too bad because it means I have to open this thread)

In regards to Math Gem's answer, from the comments I take it he has omitted some of the obvious statements; but I wonder, if one was to give every required statement, what would have to be included?

In the proof he requires $c = ba$ which surely is only a small (equal to the order of the group times the number of $c \neq 1$) section of a group. It must hold for all $a,b, c \neq 1$ so the total amount of combinations you would have to verify (say A is the group) would be $\mathrm{T} = \#A \cdot \#A \cdot (\#A-1)$. Say $\#A = x$. Since $c = ba$ is only valid for $x$ distinct couples $(a,b)$ (because of the "latin square property", $c = ba$ "misses" $\mathrm{T}-(x-1)\cdot\#A$ combinations, right?

Taking $Z_4,+$ and $2$ for example, only $2 = 2 + 0$, $2 = 0 + 2$, $2 = 1 + 3$ and $2 = 3 + 1$ so e.g. (4,4,4) and (1,2,4) are invalid for the proof given, yet we do have to take them into account. From the comments, if $ab = 1$ then clearly $ab = ba$ (because $ab = 1 \implies a = b^{-1} \implies 1 = ba$) but then there's still e.g. (4,4,4) and (1,2,4). So the trivial (4,4,4) would have to be mentioned, as well when either $a$ or $b$ is equal to $1$. From inspection of $Z_4,+$ I see that we now have all possible combinations, but should it not be proven? I.e. how do you know there do not exist $a,b, c$ such that $ba \neq c$ and $a,b \neq 1$ and yet $ab \neq ba$?

For $Z_4,+$ you can sort of say: the order is 4, so you have to check $4\cdot4\cdot3$ combinations. The proof holds for $c = ba$ and since there 3 elements in $Z_4,+$ that are not equal to $0$, you substract $4\cdot3$. Then you remove (1,b,c) and (a,1,c) so you substract $4\cdot3$ twice. Then for $ab = 1$ you substract $4\cdot3$ again and you are left with $0$. So yeah, it's true for $Z_4$, but it's not exactly a real proof. Maybe there is some peculiar group out there for which there are more elements left?

I guess you would just generalize it to some order $x$ but then I don't get $0$ like I did above.

So my  question is how do you know you have all possible combinations $a,b, c, \neq 1$ when basically your proof consists of checking different cases.

(I am a 1st year undergraduate math student, should it matter)

Comment: By the way, the hypothesis $a,b,c \ne 1$ in the link means $a \ne 1$, $b \ne 1$ and $c \ne 1$ - not just $c \ne 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I was was indeed thinking that it was only $c \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He doesn't *require* $c=ba$, he (and that is justified) uses a special case of the given condition.
What is needed to show is
$$\tag1 \forall x\forall y\colon xy=yx$$
and we are given
$$\tag2\forall a\ne1\forall b\ne1\forall c\ne1\colon  abc=cba$$
We do not have to check these $(n-1)^3$ equalities (2), we are *given* that they hold. If we consider some of the instances supoerfluous, we are free to simply ignore them.
On the contrary, we have to show the $n^2$ equalities (1).
Notably, the case $x=1$ in (1) holds for any group by the properties of the neutral element. Hence we may *assume* that $x\ne 1$.
Likewise, (1) trivially holds when $y=1$, hence we may assume that $y\ne 1$.
And finally each element commutes with its inverse, hence the case $y=x^{-1}$ is also automatically true in (1).
So we can assume $x\ne1$, $y\ne 1$, $yx\ne 1$. Thus allows us to *specialize*  (2) to (letting $a=x, b=y, c=yx$)
$$xyyx=yxyx$$
which implies (by cancelling from the right)  $$xy=yx$$ as was to be shown.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you for your clear explanation. Basically, because (2) holds for any combination a,b,c≠1, it holds in particular for the case where $c =ba$, and we choose that because that immediately gives you $ab=ba$, which is what we wanted. We could have chosen c differently but that would just make the proof more difficult. Correct? At first it seemed to me that you would be removing some of the data by making c dependent on a,b but I think it is slowly sinking in now. – svd 14 mins ago

Answer (score 5):

He doesn't *require* $c=ba$; he just fixes any $a,b$, and then applies the equality (which holds for *any* $c$, so in particular for any one you might like to consider) $$abc=cba$$ to the special case where $c$ is taken to be $ba$. This is then **sufficient** to prove that $$ab=ba$$ since you get $abba = baba$ and you can then multiply successively by $a^{-1}$ then $b^{-1}$ on the right of both sides. Since $a$, $b$ were arbitrary, this proves that $ab=ba$ for *all* elements $a$, $b$, i.e. that the group is abelian.

Comment: To put it another way, he is using a particular part of the information given only. It's like "Assuming $f(x)=x^2$ show that $f(-1)=1$" - you only need the particular case of the hypothesis where $x=-1$.

Comment: Yes — wth the slight difference that here, he uses only a small part of the information, but a possibly different one for each couple $(a,b)\in G^2$. That is, the goal is to prove $$ab=ba$$ for all pairs $(a,b)\in G^2$, given "total information" $I$; the proof proceeds by showing the relation for *each* pair $(a,b)\in G^2$, using only a subset $I_{a,b}\subset I$ of the information each time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was confused at first why [... This is then sufficient...] is true, see also my comment on @Hagen von Eitzen's reply. I think I have it now -- and I think I lost track of what actually had to be proven; i.e. (1) and not (2). We are also taught the [... arbitrary ... proves it for all elements] but that doesn't flow quite naturally with me yet, I keep thinking perhaps there's some element that behaves completely different, but I guess that doesn't make any sense. I probably just need some more practise :-)

Comment: yes, those things can seem a bit abstract at the beginning. The whole thing about taking an *arbitrary* element is that, since you don't assume *anything particular* about the element you pick, what you prove afterwards *can* be applied to **any** of them — and therefore *does* apply to any of them.

Answer (score 1):

If $abc=cba$ for any $c$ whatever, let $c=ba$. Then we have $$abba=baba$$

So that $$(abba)a^{-1}b^{-1}=(baba)a^{-1}b^{-1}$$ which reduces to $$ab=ba$$