# In a finite group we have $abc\cdots z = z\cdots cba$ . Is it abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

In a group we have $abc\cdots z = z\cdots cba$ then is it an abelian group?
It's proven for $3$ members here:

[In a group we have $abc=cba$. Is it abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299038/in-a-group-we-have-abc-cba-is-it-abelian/299040)

And I do not find a way to try an inductive proof (If it's right for three members then it's right for n members).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: In case this property holds **for all choices** of $a,b,...,z$ just take $c=d=...=z=1$, where $1$ denotes the neutral element of the group.

Comment: If $a,b,c,\dots,y, z$ are arbitrary, let each of $b,c,\dots, y$ be the identity; then $az=za$ holds for arbitrary $a,z$.

Comment: Looking at the linked question, I think it should be assumed that all elements $a,\ldots, z$ are $\ne 0$. Otherwise it’s trivial, as the other comments point out

Answer (score 0):

Following the question in the link I'll try to show the case where:

$abcd=dcba$ for all $a,b,c,d\not=1$ in $G$. It is $a'=a^{-1}$ and

\begin{align}abcd=dcba \iff \\ abcda'b'c'd'=1 \\ \iff abcd(cba)'d'=1 , \\ \ \text{ for } d=cba \\ abc(cba)'=1 \iff \\ abca'b'c'=1 \iff \\ abc(ba)'c'=1, \\ \text{ for } c=ba \\ aba'b'=1 \checkmark \end{align}

Comment: This is difficult to read. Please use the "align" $\LaTeX$ feature.

Comment: It's . . . still unclear. I don't know how you managed that.